# How to get handle of the original window when browsing a website in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to fire an event until finishing browsing of a merchant's website, say www.homedepot.home.

For example, the user goes to www.homedepot
1. once he starts browsing this website, a popup window is opened for some instruction etc and it will stay;
2. after that he can continue browsing by searching, looking at any product etc on homedepot;
3. once he finishes browsing of homedepot and close the main window, my popup window will do something.

The question here is how I can get a handle of the main window which the user is broswing in, no matter what the url is, since an event need to be fired when the last browsed page within that window is closed?

Comment: On Chrome, in the popup window, `window.opener` becomes `null` when the original window (tab) is closed. I'm not sure whether that's the case for all browsers, though.

Comment: it is working on IE and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

you can use Window object in JavaScript, when you enter to some webpage before you open a popup page you have access to Window object that represents access to current window, in the popup window you have access to Window object also, the Window object have a property named Opener that represents the caller window. by that property you can get parents events or also you can call a function on parent (opener) window

look at this 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guys input. I used if (!opener || opener.closed || opener==null), it worked for firefox, chrome and IE, but not work for Safari. Any input on how to make it work for Safari? Thanks again!